# Run a jupyter notebook in a different directory with jupyter nbconvert

Tags: python, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I've got a directory structure to my notebooks:

- main.py
- notebooks/

  - notebook.py
  - notebook.ipynb

The notebook.py file and notebook.ipynb file are linked with JupyText: we keep the .py file in source control (without outputs or metadata) and we use the .ipynb file as a regular notebook. IntelliJ gives us the opportunity to run cells from both files, but unfortunately, with different working directories. This means that referring to files becomes a real headache because the relative path begins with either ./ or ../

To fix this, I've done a filthy hack: at the root level (next to the main.py) I've defined a project_root.py with the following function:

```
def get_project_root() -> str:
    return str(Path(__file__).parent)
```

Then, from the notebook, I can do this:

```
from project_root import get_project_root
os.chdir(get_project_root())
```

and suddenly, the working directory is always the project root folder, which means all file paths are also relative to the root folder, and my headache is gone.

Enter main.py.
I've set up notebooks for each step of the process, so a notebook for loading data, a notebook for preprocessing, a notebook for analysis, a notebook for each model I want to train, etc. This is done because multiple smaller files are easier to collaborate on than one big file, and stuff is easier to find.

In my main file, I've basically done this: (abridged)

```
def run(notebook_path: str):
    os.system("jupyter nbconvert --execute {notebook_path}")

run("notebooks/notebook.ipynb")
```

This way, I can run the whole workflow in an automated fashion and test multiple parameters or models or whatever.

But the working directory of that `jupyter nbconvert` path is `notebooks/` :(
This would be fine if the project_root.py trick worked, but apparently, it can't find my python files to import either.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b3b128d3ca4d> in <module>
      3 print(os.getcwd()) # prints "~/project-root/notebooks"
      4 
----> 5 from project_root import get_project_root
      6 os.chdir(get_project_root())
      7 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_root'
```

My issue would either be fixed if I could modify the working directory for the `jupyter nbconvert` command, or if I could somehow get the python import to work another (scaleable) way. Any other suggestions are, of course, welcome.

Thank you, dear reader, for your time!

Comment: Have you considered marking the folder as Sources Root (right-click -> Mark Directory as)? This way it will be automatically added to PYTHONPATH when you start the server in IDEA so you don't need to do relative imports.
There is also a ticket in PyCharm issue tracker requesting the possibility to specify a custom working directory https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35329, but it's probably not really relevant to your case.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I solved my issue and put the solution below. You put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Sergey K. for his comment, he put me on the right track.

I did mark my project root as a sources folder, but this didn't have the effect of adding that folder to PYTHONPATH, as I'd hoped. I noticed that before doing `run ("notebooks/notebook.ipynb")`, my path looked like this: `[a, b, c, d, project_root]`. But as soon as I entered the notebook, my path was `[project_root/notebooks, a, b, c, d]`, so either it uses a separate path, or it removes the current working directory and adds a new one at the front.

On a limb, I added `project_root` to PYTHONPATH programmatically, and it started appearing in my path inside my notebook as well. This fixes my issue.

In summary: in `main.py`, run this once (every IDE startup for me, idk why):

```
from project_root import get_project_root

if get_project_root() not in os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep):
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] + os.pathsep + get_project_root()
```